# pysnmp mac to human readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

I am using pysnmp to get a list of IP and mac address from ipNetToMediaPhysAddress
This is working with no issue.
I have a problem however converting the mac address to human readable one.
the SNMP code has caused the mac to appear as

```
0x05056bdafc
```

I am wondering how to convert this to a human readable mac address.
I understand that some 0's are missing as per details here - http://blog.colovirt.com/2009/05/05/linuxnetworkingvmware-snmpwalk-mac-address-missing-0s/

Is there some code or a way using pysnmp to covert it to human readable?

Cheers for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `netaddr` package. If you're working on Ubuntu/Debian you can easily install it this way:

```
# apt-get install python-netaddr
```

Alternatively you can install it with `pip` in a virtualenv or Python3 venv:

```
$ source myenvironment/bin/activate
$ pip install netaddr
```

Then you can try this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from netaddr import *
>>> mac = EUI(0x05056bdafc)
>>> 
>>> print mac
00-05-05-6B-DA-FC
>>>
```

or with Python 3:

```
$ python
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from netaddr import * 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> mac = EUI(0x05056bdafc)
>>> 
>>> print (mac)
00-05-05-6B-DA-FC
>>>
>>> mac.dialect = mac_unix
>>> 
>>> print (mac)
0:5:5:6b:da:fc
```

You can find more examples [here](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_02.html#).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was making the mistake of putting the hex address inside quotes and that's why it didn't work when i first tried. Thank you for you assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The SNMP way would be to use MIB(s) to resolve all received values into human-friendly form. The lookupValues=True flag in this [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v2c-with-mib-resolution.html) does the trick. However you would  first have to: A) convert your conventional MIB and all other MIBs it depends on into pysnmp format and B) load your pysnmp-MIBs to your pysnmp-based app (through MibVariable.loadMibs()).

Alternatively, if you know exact OIDs whose value is a MAC, then the following piece of code may help:

```
>>> from pysnmp.smi import builder
>>> mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
>>> MacAddress, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-TC', 'MacAddress')
>>> macAddress = MacAddress(hexValue='05056bdafc'.zfill(12))
>>> macAddress.prettyPrint()
'00:05:05:6b:da:fc'
```

Or it could probably be done just in Python:

```
>>> mac = '05056bdafc'.zfill(12)
>>> ':'.join([ mac[i:i+2] for i in range(0, 12, 2) ])
'00:05:05:6b:da:fc'
```